# Looking for efficient data recovery software

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, storage, data-recovery

Deleted a folder (just regular old empty trash) on my MacBook Pro internal SSD that I thought I was backed up, turns out it wasn't. I stopped using the computer as to preserve the blocks where the data is written and booted up an old computer to do recovery. I Don't have any experience with data recovery software, wondering if anyone knows any good applications? Preferably that allow me to preview deleted data before I pay for the application (or if there's a free one that I'm overlooking? But I'm not hopeful about that). Lots of things come up on google but it's hard to differentiate one from another in terms of quality.

Comment: We’ll get this to the main thread on data recovery options. Start with ProSoft engineering’s tool would be my advice. If you want to edit this based on documenting some requirements - see [meta] on how to ask software recommendation questions - an edit will review the close / hold.